# Is it possible to express $(\sin(x))^x$ as a complex number, if it is, then how is it done?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have looked at the graph and I know it is real for all $x$ that satisfy
$2\pi \mathbb{Z} <x<2 \pi (\mathbb{Z}+1)$ and imaginary or complex for all other $x$. I want to know if it is possible to express this equation as $f(x)+g(x) i$ where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real for all real domain.

Comment: @AjayMishra can you please elaborate on that an use it to answer my question? I am still having a bit of trouble.

Comment: Is $x$ real? Then $\sin(x)^x$ is just a real number, I'm not sure what kind of expression as a complex number you're seeking for.

Comment: Yay, you generally calculate $z^w$ as $\exp(w\ln z)$, where you use a branch cut to define $\ln z$. @YiFan Well, it gets complicated if $\sin(x)$ is negative and $x$ is not a rational number with odd denominator (and even then you could argue over branch cuts).

Comment: Is it $\sin(x^x)$ or $\sin^x (x)$?

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh the second one, I’ll clarify that in my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble you run into is that $b^a$ generally needs to be handled as a *multi-valued* expression in contexts like this where $a$ is not an integer and $b$ is not a positive real.

What this means is that for most values of $x$ there are many *different* complex numbers that all have about equally good claims to be $\sin(x)^x$. When $\sin(x)\ge 0$ one of those choices will be real, and it's useful to declare that to be *the* value of $\sin(x)^x$, but we're not so lucky for the $\sin(x)<0$.

If we really have to select one of the choices, there's one of them called the "principal value" of the expression -- but note that this is still a quite arbitrary choice (and especially so when the base of the exponent is a negative real).

With all these caveats, deciding to use the principal value leads us to (for real $x$ only):
$$ \sin(x)^x = |\sin(x)|^x\cos(\theta(x)) + i |\sin(x)|^x\sin(\theta(x)) $$
where the helper function $\theta$ can be defined as
$$ \theta(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } \sin(x) \ge 0 \\
\pi x & \text{when } \sin(x) < 0 \end{cases} $$

(The other possible values arise by adding some multiple of $2\pi x$ to $\theta(x)$).

---

How does this work? We start by defining $e^z$ for all complex numbers $z$, giving the quite robustly defined complex [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)
$$ e^{x+iy} = e^x\cos(y) + i e^x\sin(y) $$
Then we can define $b^a$ to mean $e^{ca}$ where $c$ is some complex number such that $e^c=b$. However, there are always many choices for $c$ that satisfy this -- and that is where the multi-valuedness $c$ comes in. By convention the "principal" $c$ means the one whose imaginary part is in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

When $\sin x=0$ this definition won't work. We get at least a *continuous* function here if we follow common convention and set $\sin(0)^0=0^0=1$ but $\sin(n\pi)^{n\pi} = 0^{n\pi}=0$ for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I’ll probably accept and give the bounty to it in a couple of days

Answer (score 3):

We generalize the logarithm to be
$$
\log x=\log|x|+i\theta,
$$
where $\theta=0$ if $x>0$ and $\theta=\pi$, when $x<0$.

It is $\log(\sin x)=\log|\sin(x)|+i\theta$, where $\theta=0$ if $x\in(2k\pi,2k\pi+\pi)=D_1(k)$, $k\in\textbf{Z}$ and $\theta=\pi$ if $x\in(2k\pi+\pi,2k\pi+2\pi)=D_2(k)$.

Hence when $k\neq 0$, we have
$$
\sin(x)^x=e^{x\log(\sin x)}=|\sin x|^x\in\textbf{R}\textrm{, if }x\in D_1(k)
$$
and
$$
\sin(x)^x=e^{x\log(\sin x)}=e^{x\log|\sin x|+ix\pi}=|\sin x|^{x}e^{i\pi x}\textrm{, if }x\in D_2(k)
$$

For the case $x\rightarrow 0$, we have

**1.** When $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$:
$$
\frac{2 x}{\pi}<\sin x\leq x\textrm{, }\forall x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right).\tag 1
$$
Hence
$$
x\log\left(\frac{2x}{\pi}\right)<x\log\sin x<x \log x\textrm{, }\forall x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$ Hence knowing that $\lim_{x\rightarrow{0}^+}x\log x=0$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}x\log\sin x=0.\tag 2
$$
and consequently
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(\sin x)^x=1
$$
**2.** When $x\rightarrow 0^{-}$: We have $(\sin x)^x=e^{x\log|\sin x|+ix\pi}=e^{x\log\sin(-x)+ix\pi}\textrm{, }\forall x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{4},0\right)
$ and if we set $h=-x>0$, then $(\sin x)^x=e^{-h\log \sin h-ih\pi}$, $\forall h\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.
Hence in the same way we get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}x\log(|\sin x|)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}x\log(\sin(-x))=-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}h\log\sin h=0.
$$
and consequently
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}(\sin x)^x=1
$$
**3.** When $x\rightarrow \pi^{+}$, we get that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^{+}}\log\sin x=-\infty$ and consequently
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^{+}}(\sin x)^x=0.
$$
and when $x\rightarrow \pi^{-}$, we get that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^{-}}\log\sin x=-\infty$ and consequently
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^{-}}(\sin x)^x=0.
$$

**4.** The cases $x\rightarrow 2\pi^{-}$ and $x\rightarrow 2\pi^{+}$ are the same with 3.
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 2\pi^{+}}(\sin x)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2\pi^{-}}(\sin x)^x=0.
$$